# Java Web App: Passing form parameters across multiple pages

Tags: java, servlets

what is the best practice or best way of passing form parameters from page to page in a flow?  If I have a flow where a user enters data in a form and hits next and repeats this process until they get to an approval page, what ways could I approach this problem to make the retention of data as simple as possible over the flow?

I guess you could put all the information as you go in the session but could you get into memory issues if a lot of people are using your app and going through the flow at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpSession is your best bet if you want to track a "wizard" style data entry.
Just seconding @Rachel's openion.

The server side component that handles your page submits ( such as Servlets) would have some code like:

```
public void doPost (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException    
{
    HttpSession session = req.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("Variable1", request.getParameter("input1"));
    //and so on..
```

HttpSession Provides a way to identify a user across more than one page request or visit to a Web site and to store information about that user.

Comment: Indeed. Http is stateless so sessions are the way to go. As for memory issues, this depends on the server and the way the JVM is configured.

Comment: `HttpSession#putValue()` is **deprecated** since Servlet 2.2 (>10 years ago). Use `HttpSession#setAttribute()` instead. Also, you can just use `request.getSession()` without the boolean to get it regardless of whether it's already created or not.

Comment: Yep @BalusC +1 .. long long time ago was it when I coded a raw servlet

Comment: Since you didn't, I was so kind to edit the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You can store data into [Cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) or store them into [Session](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_%28computer_science%29) and access them between different web pages.

Answer (score 0):

You may also put attributes in the request scope.  They are accessed the same way from EL in your JSPs, but do not require a session.  Depending on your situation, you may not wish to start sessions for every user.